# Is there a way to get a 0th level Psionic Power outside of feats, class levels, and racial choice?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, psionics

I'm looking to be able to manifest a specific 0th level power as an entry requirement into a PrC, the specific power being *Far Hand*.  All I've found for gaining a power would be via certain races, taking a level in a manifesting class, or the Unlocked Talent feat.  Are there any permanent methods of gaining this power?

Note: Dreamscarred Press material is mostly allowed in the game I will be joining.

Answer (score 1):

Psionic rules are only found in splatbooks by a specific 3rd party publisher.  They are a good 3PP, but they are still a 3PP and so the stuff they publish doesn't benefit from the sheer volume of material available as options in the Paizo material or other publishers' splatbooks.

There are traits and a rogue talent that give characters access to 0-level spells.

The extant traits pretty much all read "Benefit: Choose a 0-level spell. You may cast that spell once per day as a spell-like ability. This is cast at your highest caster level gained; if you have no caster level, it functions at CL 1st" with differing fluff intros and trait categories.  There are a bunch of these, and a couple that are so close as to not be worth mentioning.

The only notable trait that goes above and beyond the previous ability is "Infernal Bastard" from the Council of Thieves Player's Guide, which gives you a 0-level of your choice from any class as an at-will spell-like ability (in exchange for several sacrifices).

Making up traits that do something similar for psionics will fix your problem and help integrate psionics into the trait system.

The Minor Magic rogue talent lets you pick one 0-level spell from the sorcerer/wizard list and cast that spell thrice a day.  Wizards don't get the best 0-level spells, so this isn't that great even compared to the 1/day traits.

Making up a rogue talent that does this will let you do this but, if you model the talent off the extant *Minor Magic* talent, will be somewhat underpowered.

I haven't run games with psionic traits or rogue talents, so I can't give you advice on exactly what trait/talent to use.  I have run splatbook material in general before, and these sorts of changes are generally necessary if you want splatbook classes and subsystems to keep up with all the options the base classes get.

Comment: Yeah I've asked the GM about allowing a Psionic background trait similar to the Magical Talent trait so far and whether it would count for this circumstance.  I checked out the psionic content on the PFSRD and didn't find anything, I'm not sure if there was a trait in a book that didn't make it to the PFSRD though.

Comment: They also cannot match Paizo’s volume because they have *standards*.